# Heroku app doesn't work properly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my heroku app. When I go to the URL, it just shows me a blank screen. In the browser console, it tells me:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <             main.ac26b187.js:1
```

I check the heroku logs. I see this:

```
2018-04-19T11:14:00.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user bijman@kth.se
2018-04-19T11:15:59.535210+00:00 app[api]: Release v17 created by user bijman@kth.se
2018-04-19T11:15:59.535210+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 61af7a73 by user bijman@kth.se
2018-04-19T11:14:00.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-04-19T11:16:01.505173+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-04-19T11:16:15.810911+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `yarn start`
2018-04-19T11:16:18.879765+00:00 app[web.1]: yarn run v1.6.0
2018-04-19T11:16:18.948747+00:00 app[web.1]: warning package.json: No license field
2018-04-19T11:16:19.169851+00:00 app[web.1]: $ node index.js
2018-04-19T11:16:20.744933+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on port 8323
2018-04-19T11:16:21.406512+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-04-19T11:17:09.689972+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=sentify-kth.herokuapp.com request_id=6a2f6010-62a4-4e7a-a07e-d9c71ace8fbe fwd="81.227.66.93" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=136ms status=200 bytes=1029 protocol=https
2018-04-19T11:17:09.855575+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/NiekBijman/Sentify/static/js/main.ac26b187.js" host=sentify-kth.herokuapp.com request_id=001fb771-cb31-4d06-a938-b79d40dad97a fwd="81.227.66.93" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=25ms status=200 bytes=1029 protocol=https
2018-04-19T11:17:09.849774+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/NiekBijman/Sentify/static/css/main.b9e635e3.css" host=sentify-kth.herokuapp.com request_id=7f2ff9ee-01e0-4cbb-ac0c-e36190c8a027 fwd="81.227.66.93" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=26ms status=200 bytes=1029 protocol=https
2018-04-19T11:17:10.057003+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=sentify-kth.herokuapp.com request_id=e88cf8b8-c26e-4a22-8305-236f9191668c fwd="81.227.66.93" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=1029 protocol=https
2018-04-19T11:17:13.818146+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/NiekBijman/Sentify/static/css/main.b9e635e3.css" host=sentify-kth.herokuapp.com request_id=266bebd7-58df-4106-b383-ca14cd85cc1e fwd="81.227.66.93" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
```

but it honestly doesn't tell me much.

I started getting this error when I started messing around with the package.json and index.js files (index.js was previously called server.js but I renamed it). Therefore, here are those files:

[image]

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "sentify-server",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "client": "cd client && yarn start",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && yarn --production=false && yarn run build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^5.0.1",
    "ejs": "^2.5.8",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "fetch-tweets": "^0.1.7",
    "firebase": "^4.12.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.1.2",
    "request": "^2.85.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0"
  }
}
```

client/package.json:

```
{
  "name": "sentify",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/icons": "^1.0.0-beta.42",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mapbox-gl": "^0.44.2",
    "material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.41",
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-d3-basic": "^1.6.11",
    "react-d3-core": "^1.3.9",
    "react-d3-shape": "^0.3.25",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "react-simple-pie-chart": "^0.5.0",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },

  "devDependencies": {},
  "description": "## Setup 1. First, make sure that you have **Node Package Manager** (npm) installed on your system. To check if you have Node.js installed, run this command in your terminal:`node -v` To confirm that you have npm installed you can run this command in your terminal:`npm -v`. To update your npm, type this into your terminal: `npm install npm@latest -g` 2. Go to the root of the Repository and run `npm install`. Let it    install all the dependencies. 3. Run `npm start` through the terminal. This will start the webserver and the application should pop up in your    browser ready for use. Alternatively you can open in through [http://localhost:3000]. Whenever you make changes in your code and save, the browser will update automatically, so you don't have to click refresh anymore. 4. **IMPORTANT** Our config.js file contains our API Keys which is why we put it in .gitignore.  @team, you can find the config.js file in the Slack channel.    4. Make sure to update the dependencies in the **package.json**. Updating all the dependencies is possble by `npm install <pkg> --save`. It will append the dependencies to your existing **package.json** file.",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/NiekBijman/Sentify.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/NiekBijman/Sentify/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/NiekBijman/Sentify#readme",
  "main": "./frontend/src/index.js",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const FetchTweets = require('fetch-tweets');
const request = require('request');
var path = require("path");

const TW_URL = "http://1.1/search/tweets.json"  // Twitter search URL
const SEN_URL =  "http://www.sentiment140.com/api/bulkClassifyJson" // URL of sentiment analysis

var TW_KEYS = {
  consumer_key: process.env.TW_KEY,
  consumer_secret: process.env.TW_SECRET
}

const app = express();
const fetchTweets = new FetchTweets(TW_KEYS);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// Priority serve any static files.
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"){
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html'));
  });
}

// For getting tweets like /api/twitter?q=hello&geocode=234523 etc.
app.get('/api/twitter', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("Getting tweets")
    const options = {
      q : req.query.q,
      lang: "en",
      result_type: "popular",
      count: 100,
    }
    try{
      await fetchTweets.byTopic(options, function(results){
        console.log("sending results")
        res.send(results)
      })
    }catch (error){
      console.log(error)
    }
})

app.get('/api/sentiment', async (req, res) => {
  const options = {
    q : req.query.q,
    lang : "en",
    count : 100,
  }
  try{
    fetchTweets.byTopic(options, async function(results){
      const tweets = {"data": results.map(function(tweet){
        return {"text": tweet.body, "query": options.q}
      })}
      var body = JSON.stringify(tweets)

      // get sentiments
      const sentiments = await fetch(SEN_URL, {method: "POST", body: body})
      const json = await sentiments.json()
      const data = json.data

      // calculate percentages
      const response = {positive: undefined, neutral: undefined, negative: undefined}
      var numPos = 0
      var numNeu = 0
      var numNeg = 0
      data.forEach(function(tweet){
        switch(tweet.polarity){
          case 4:
            numPos += 1
            break
          case 2:
            numNeu += 1
            break
          case 0:
            numNeg += 1
            break
        }
      })
      const tot = numPos + numNeu + numNeg
      response.positive = numPos/tot
      response.neutral = numNeu/tot
      response.negative = numNeg/tot
      // send response
      res.send(response)
    })
  }catch (error){
    console.log(error)
  }
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`))
```

What is causing this error? PS: if you need any additional info, let me know. I'm quite new at this so not sure exactly what you need.

EDIT: After changing `*` to `/` in

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html'));
  });
```

AND putting that route in the bottom of the file (but before `.listen`), I got these errors instead:

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://sentify-kth.herokuapp.com/NiekBijman/Sentify/static/css/main.b9e635e3.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
sentify-kth.herokuapp.com/:1 GET https://sentify-kth.herokuapp.com/NiekBijman/Sentify/static/js/main.ac26b187.js net::ERR_ABORTED
sentify-kth.herokuapp.com/:1 Refused to apply style from 'https://sentify-kth.herokuapp.com/NiekBijman/Sentify/static/css/main.b9e635e3.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
sentify-kth.herokuapp.com/:1 Refused to execute script from 'https://sentify-kth.herokuapp.com/NiekBijman/Sentify/static/js/main.ac26b187.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
favicon.ico:1 GET https://sentify-kth.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: I went to your app link and saw that `main.ac26b187.js` is actually a html file. Whats the content of your public folder?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. What do you mean by public folder?

Comment: Inside the client, you have a public folder, what files do you have in there? Especifically your js folder

Comment: On both heroku bash and my local machine, there is only a single file, called index.html.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with your build process, unfortunately I don't know enough to be able to help, but from what I can see, after you build both your .js and .css files end up with the same content as your index page. [Open the Sources tab of the dev tool and check their contents](http://prntscr.com/j7bzb3)

Comment: Actually, I just saw something. In your index.js, you are forwarding every request to your index.html. This line `app.get('*', (req, res)` , maybe that should be `'/'` instead of a *

Comment: I tried. It didn't solve the problem but it changed the error message. I've put it in an edit

Comment: Please try with `'/*'` instead

Comment: That results in the original error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169348/discussion-between-dubonzi-and-sahand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By checking your git repo, I assume the changes we discussed in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169348/discussion-between-dubonzi-and-sahand) worked for you, so I'll put them here in case someone else runs into the same problem.

---

In your `index.js` file, you are forwarding every request to your `index.html`.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"){
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html'));
  });
}
```

By using `*`, everytime the browser makes a request to the server, the server will respond sending the html file back. You should change that to a `'/'` so the file is only sent back when the user access the index of your application

```
...
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
...
```

You can read more in the [create-react-app docs](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#other-solutions)

Another thing you'll have to change is the `homepage` attribute in the client's `package.json` to `homepage: '.'` , react uses that attribute to determine the path to your files and since your client isn't in the root of the application, react might be not be able to find the files properly.

Check the docs [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#serving-the-same-build-from-different-paths) for more info.